# NZSQL/CODE - How to use a ESCAPE or Specify a Rang using []

Tags: sql, netezza

We are trying to find out if there is a similar function/way to specify a LIKE condition using a range, instead of an exact charector. In TSQL we were able to accomplish this by using

```
WHERE Col1 LIKE '%[^A-Z]%'
```

This would then go through and look for any letter between A & Z. I have been able to find similar ways to do this by using the ESCAPE function in Oracle, but have not been able to find a solution for TSQL.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Netezza SQL hews pretty closely to the ANSI SQL 92 standard in general, and definitely in this case.  The only metacharacters support with LIKE are'%' and '_'.

The SQL Extension Toolkit has several regex functions that can do this by allowing you to use general regular expression to do matching, though. For example, regex_instr:

```
select * from regex_table order by col1;                   
COL1
-------
 12340
 12345
 1234A
 1234B
 1234C
 1234a
 1234b
(7 rows)


select * from regex_table where regexp_instr(col1,'\d{4}[A-Z]') > 0 order by col1;
 COL1
-------
 1234A
 1234B
 1234C
(3 rows)
```

Or for case insensitivity:

```
select * from regex_table where regexp_instr(col1,'\d{4}[A-Z]','i') > 0 order by col1;
 COL1
-------
 1234A
 1234B
 1234C
 1234a
 1234b
(5 rows)
```

For your particular example, if your admin won't make the SQL Extension Toolkit available to you, you could use the standard SUBSTR function like this:

```
select * from regex_table where substr(col1,5,1) between 'A' and 'Z' order by col1;
 COL1
-------
 1234A
 1234B
 1234C
(3 rows)
```

Or if you wanted it to be case insensitive:

```
select * from regex_table where upper(substr(col1,5,1)) between 'A' and 'Z' order by col1;
 COL1
-------
 1234A
 1234B
 1234C
 1234a
 1234b
(5 rows)
```

With Netezza, all the ESCAPE clause will do for you is allow you to change the escape character when you want to escape a metacharacter in a LIKE clause.  Normally this character is '\'.  So if you wanted to match a literal '%' in a LIKE clause instead of having it be a wildcard, you could prefix it with a '\'.  Using the ESCAPE clause would like you use an alternate character like this:

```
select * from regex_table;
 COL1
------
 %BC
 ABC
(2 rows)

select * from regex_table where col1 like '%BC';
 COL1
------
 %BC
 ABC
(2 rows)

TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> select * from regex_table where col1 like '\%BC';
 COL1
------
 %BC
(1 row)

select * from regex_table where col1 like '#%BC' escape '#';
 COL1
------
 %BC
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, given that the ESCAPE looks for that specific character, is there another way to specify a range? Essentially my column contains numbers and then some entries have a letter ranging between A-Z at character 5. Is there a way in Netezza to specify to look for a letter in that range?

Comment: Not with LIKE.  The only metacharacters supported there are '%' which matches to any number (including zero) of any characters, and '_" which matches with exactly one of any character.  I updated the answer to speak to that specific example.

Comment: Thanks again, Scott. I keep finding that we run into a lot of things that could be resolved by the SQL Extensions so I think we may have to go that route. In the meantime, using the BETWEEN 'A' AND 'Z' seems to be doing the trick, as it can also be used as a NOT BETWEEN. 

Thank you again for all your help!